# Unexpected error when i try to set parameters on a function to be default

Tags: c, arrays, eclipse, function

I'm trying to initialize or declare a value in a function to be default, but when i do this the compiler throws an error there on line 3 
void makeGrid(char arr[8],char c ,int index =10);
"expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token". I looked on internet some examples of how to set a parameter to be default but, when i paste the code of the examples i didn't run either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXVALUE 10

void makeGrid(char arr[8],char c ,int index =10);
void decition(int n);
char grid[8];

void makeGrid(char arr[8], char c, int index){
    if(index!=10){
        arr[index] = c;
        printf(" %c ", arr[index]);
    }else{
        for(int i =0; i <=8; i++){
            arr[i] = i+1;
            printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
            if(i==0 || i== 1 || i==3 ||i==4 ||i==6 ||i==7) printf("¦");
            if(i==2 || i== 5 || i==8) printf("\n___¦___¦___\n");
        }
    }
}

void decition(int n){
    int index = n-1;
    char newGrid[8];
    makeGrid(newGrid,'x',index);
}


int main(){
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    int n;
    printf("\t\t\t      Tic Tac Toe Game\n");
    printf("\t\t\t Player 1 is X, Player 2 is O\n");
    makeGrid(grid, 'c', 10);
    printf("player 1 enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    decition(n);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C does not support default values for function arguments.

This feature is however supported in C++.